# Minimal Hakyll site

Tags: haskell, static-site, hakyll

I understand there's an example site given by

```
hakyll-init app
```

But I'm looking to reduce even more to the skeleton, and just have 1 markdown page that renders in the root, "`localhost:8000/`", and an alias "`localhost:8000/index.html`."

From the instructions, I have created this:

```
.
├── app
│   ├── app.cabal
│   ├── _cache
│   │   └── d5c19886a1234f571c624d44ba520d2b
│   ├── css
│   │   └── default.css
│   ├── images
│   ├── index.markdown
│   ├── _site
│   │   ├── css
│   │   │   └── default.css
│   │   └── images
│   ├── site.hs
│   ├── stack.yaml
│   └── templates
│       └── default.html
```

And I have the following in:

## site.hs

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
{-# LANGUAGE OverloadedStrings #-}
import           Data.Monoid (mappend)
import           Hakyll


--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
main :: IO ()
main = hakyll $ do
    match "images/*" $ do
        route   idRoute
        compile copyFileCompiler

    match "css/*" $ do
        route   idRoute
        compile compressCssCompiler

    match "index.markdown" $ do
        route   $ "index" + setExtension "html"
        compile $ pandocCompiler
            >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" defaultContext
            >>= relativizeUrls

    create "/" $ do
        route   $ "index" + setExtension "html"
        compile $ pandocCompiler
            >>= loadAndApplyTemplate "templates/default.html" defaultContext
            >>= relativizeUrls

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
postCtx :: Context String
postCtx =
    dateField "date" "%B %e, %Y" `mappend`
    defaultContext
```

This seems to compile:

```
app $ stack exec site watch
Listening on http://127.0.0.1:8000
Initialising...
  Creating store...
  Creating provider...
  Running rules...
Checking for out-of-date items
Compiling
Success
```

But when I load `http://127.0.0.1:8000`, or `http://localhost:8000/index.html`, I don't see my template, I see:

```
File not found
```

How can I fix `site.hs` for a minimal Hakyll (only an `index.html` created from a markdown stub), and how can I understand the debugging better?  Eg, here I would have liked to see some kind of "stuff won't be found" at compile time.  Where would I look for that?

Comment: Hum, where did you get that `"index" + setExtension ".html"` syntax? I have `route   $ setExtension "html"`

Comment: Indeed, that should not even compile `(+)` is defined on `Num` typeclass, which `Routes` produced by `setExtension` come nowhere near.

Comment: Did you call `stack build` or `cabal build` after editing the source code?

Comment: Was trying to concatenate.  Changed to '++.'

Comment: @Mittenchops That will not work either. `setExtension` does not return `String`, it just sets the extension (think imperatively).

Comment: @JanTojnar, now that I stopped the watch process, when I try to rebuild or clean, I get: 
```  [ERROR] Hakyll.Core.Compiler.Require.load: templates/default.html (snapshot _final) was not found in the cache, the cache might be corrupted or the item you are referring to might not exist```
The templates/default.html definitely does exist.